# Print Yesterday's date

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, visual-studio-2008, datetime-format

I want to print yesterday's date in this particular format "20.08.2014" in vb.net.

Can someone share the piece of code please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Now` to get the current date (and time)

Use `.AddDays` with -1 as the argument to remove one day from it

Use the `.ToString` overload of the `DateTime` object to specify the date or time format you require:

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

References

[DateTime.Now Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)

[DateTime.AddDays Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: + 1 Oops. Sorry. I had so many tabs opened and didn't realize that you had already replied. My sincere apologies :)

Comment: I have deleted my answer. :)